# proper way to insert an image into an array set in react typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to call a random image from an array set. It is calling them but their is some weird bug I cant figure out. It does call them but I do not think this is the proper syntax.

```
export function trumpImage() {
    var trumpSet = [
        <img src="../../public/imgs/animations/trump133.png" />,
        <img src="../../public/imgs/animations/trump15624.png" />,
        <img src="../../public/imgs/animations/trump233.png" />

         

    ];
    
    const trumps = Math.floor((Math.random() * trumpSet.length));
    var randomTrump = trumpSet[trumps];

  
    return (
        randomTrump
    )
}
```

Comment: what issue are you having ?

Comment: One image is in one spot then the other two appear in another spot. I call the function in a div that I have css for and the css applied to only the one image the other two go bezerk.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this

```
export function trumpImage() {
  var trumpSet = [
    "../../public/imgs/animations/trump133.png",
    "../../public/imgs/animations/trump15624.png",
    "../../public/imgs/animations/trump233.png"
  ];

  const trumps = Math.floor((Math.random() * trumpSet.length));

  return trumpSet[trumps];
}
```

And use the function wherever you want to display in img tag like,

```
<img src={trumpImage()} />,
```

Comment: thats what I tried first and it just returns the file path as a string

Comment: oh I see. yeah it is getting the same result. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using png and I didn't think the image dimension size mattered because I used an alpha channel to only use the actual frame of image, so the div was like 900px wide and that was causing the weird behavior. Thanks everyone.